# Fixing "A start job is running for load kernel module ef i_pstore (time/no limit)" when booting

Tags: boot, boot-repair, grub-efi

When I try to boot my PC that runs Ubuntu, it gets stucks on the welcome page and when I press any key it displays lot of messages with last one being "***A start job is running for load kernel module ef i_pstore (time/no limit)***"

How can I fix this?